# Python requests - fetch and save images while there are pages

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to fetch a bunch of images, from an uncertain number of pages, and keep saving all images to a folder while there are new pages to be hit.

The code:

```
def get_player_images_with_api():

    url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=274&altIds=true&page={page}&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=274'
    img_url = 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/{player_id}.png'
    headers = {'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com'}
    my_path = 'images/players_250x250'

    page=0
    while True:
        try:
            data = requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).json()
            # uncoment this to print all data:
            # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
            for player in data['content']:
                print('{:<50} {}'.format(player['name']['display'], img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta'])))

                fullfilename = os.path.join(my_path, player['name']['display'] + ".png")
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta']), fullfilename)
                sleep(2)
            page+=1
        except:
            break
```

But the code is breaking after first page, and only images from first page are being saved to path.

However, If I comment out these lines:

```
#fullfilename = os.path.join(my_path, player['name']['display'] + ".png")
#urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta']), fullfilename)
```

All dozens of pages are printed fine.

---

What am I missing?

Comment: yeah, it was a `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`. you can answer so i can accept it

Comment: Look at the `except: break` clause. It's an extremely bad practice: it eats the error that you're having, without reporting it. Change it to `except (Exception as ex): print(ex); break`, This exception break your loop and prevents you from seeing the other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the part with `urllib.request` and replaced it with `requests` module + specified the `headers=` parameter.

Running this script it goes through pages and saves the images:

```
import os
from time import sleep
import requests

def get_player_images_with_api():

    url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=274&altIds=true&page={page}&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=274'
    img_url = 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/{player_id}.png'
    headers = {'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com'}
    my_path = 'images/players_250x250'

    page=0
    while True:
        try:
            print('Page {}...'.format(page))
            data = requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).json()
            # uncoment this to print all data:
            # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
            for player in data['content']:
                pic = img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta'])
                print('{:<50} {}'.format(player['name']['display'], pic))

                fullfilename = os.path.join(my_path, player['name']['display'] + ".png")

                r = requests.get(pic, stream=True, headers=headers)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    with open(fullfilename, 'wb') as f:
                        for chunk in r:
                            f.write(chunk)
                # sleep(2)
            page+=1
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            break

get_player_images_with_api()
```

Prints and saves the images:

```
    Page 0...
    Max Aarons                                         https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p232980.png
    Abdul Rahman Baba                                  https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p118335.png
    Tammy Abraham                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p173879.png
    Adam Smith                                         https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p54469.png
    Che Adams                                          https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p200439.png
    Dennis Adeniran                                    https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p183645.png
    Albert Adomah                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p49773.png
    Adrián                                             https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p60706.png
    Adrien Silva                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p46483.png
    Benik Afobe                                        https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p88498.png
    Sergio Agüero                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p37572.png
    Daniel Agyei                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p207725.png
    Soufyan Ahannach                                   https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p134293.png
    Ahmed El Mohamady                                  https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p37339.png
    Albian Ajeti                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p181008.png
    Nathan Aké                                         https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p126184.png
    Alberto Moreno                                     https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p100059.png
    Marc Albrighton                                    https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p51938.png
    Toby Alderweireld                                  https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p55605.png
    Aleix García                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p178871.png
    Trent Alexander-Arnold                             https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p169187.png
    Ali Koiki                                          https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p432793.png
    Alisson                                            https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p116535.png
    Allan                                              https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p214275.png
    Miguel Almirón                                     https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p179018.png
    Marcos Alonso                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p82263.png
    Steven Alzate                                      https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p235382.png
    Ibrahim Amadou                                     https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p128348.png
    Daniel Amartey                                     https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p155569.png
    Luke Amos                                          https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p168764.png
    Page 1...
    Ethan Ampadu                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p199598.png
    Joseph Anang                                       https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p447879.png

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

> In those 2 lines there is an exception happening.Try to to catch the exception .

Change to

```
 except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        # Take some action if you want.
        break
```

You can also catch specific exception by adding multiple `except`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is stopping whenever there is a exception. But instead, you can just skip the download mechanism whenever there is an error. :)

```py
 except:
    continue
```

NOTE : This will also forbid you from pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to quit whenever you want to cancel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. You can use KeyboardInterrupt class to catch that exception.